# WebSocket connection works in local machine but not in server

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, websocket, centos

I am using the Laravel Framework and [BrainSocket](http://brainsocket.brainboxmedia.ca/) to open up a websocket service in a port via the following command line:

```
php artisan brainsocket:start --port=7778
```

Afterwards, I connect to the websocket on the client-side, like so:

```
var websocket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:7778/');
```

At first I was developing this application on my local machine and everything was working fine. However, on the production server (CentOS 7 + Nginx), when I run the above line the following error message appears:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:7778/' failed: Connection
>   closed before receiving a handshake response

I tried changing the IP for the server's IP address, I have already checked if the port was being used and I made sure socket support was enabled. But whatever I do the same error message appears.

Answer (score 0):

It worked once I used port 443 instead.